# Dificuldade ao usar Invoke-RestMethod no Powershell

Tags: powershell

Estou tentando criar um script em PowerShell, e nesse script eu preciso pegar dados de uma aplicação em webservice, e ao fazer o mesmo, apenas retorna como um arrayListObject, ao invés dos objetos em si.

O script é o seguite:

```
$dados = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://IPADDRESS/DADOS' -Method 'Get'
```

Já tentei também:

```
$dados = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://IPADDRESS/DADOS' | ConvertTo-Json
$dados = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri 'http://IPADDRESS/DADOS' -Method 'Get' -ContentType "application/json"
```

O que retorna é são todos os objetos na variável $dados, em uma arrayListObject, e não consigo manipular os objetos dentro desse array. Eu não consigo selecionar $dados.data, por exemplo, apenas $dados.arrayListObject.

Comment: Seria bom informar o endereço onde está pegando os dados para também fazermos testes já que a documentação do do cmdlet [Invoke-RestMethod](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod?view=powershell-7.1#outputs) informa que a saída do cmdlet depende do formato do conteúdo recuperado e se a solicitação retornar strings JSON, `Invoke-RestMethod` retorna um `PSObject` que representa as strings. Já tentou [`ConvertTo-Json`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: O endereço é de uma intranet que usamos, por isso achei melhor não compartilhar, uma vez que não seria possível acessar. Em relação ao ConvertTo-Json, sim ja tentei usar, porém sem sucesso.

Comment: faça um [curl](https://curl.se/windows/) no mesmo endereço e veja se retorna JSON. Exemplo: `curl http://IPADDRESS/DADOS -H "Accept: application/json"`

Comment: Não obtive sucesso ao usar o curl, porém ao após algumas pesquisas, consegui pegar o header da página pelo Invoke-WebRequest, em que diz: [Content-Type, application/json;charset=UTF-8]